# How to Create a Method with 'new' keyword in its method signature using codedom

Tags: c#, .net, codedom

I want to dynamically generate a method with 'new' keyword in its method signature using codedom.  Want to generate something like this

```
private new void MyMethod()
{ 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
CodeMemberMethod myMethodMethod = new CodeMemberMethod();
myMethodMethod.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private | MemberAttributes.New;
myMethodMethod.Name = "MyMethod";
```

It is a `MemberAttributes`: `MemberAttributes.New`.

Comment: Thank you xanatos. Thats what i want.

Answer (score 1):

When you call [`TypeBuilder.DefineMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf36892y(v=vs.110).aspx), just include [`MethodAttributes.NewSlot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodattributes(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Indicates that the method always gets a new slot in the vtable.